# read docx file with javascript in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, docx

i'm trying to read docx file

```
(function(){
var serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile = "/sites/sitecollection/mysite/assets/file.docx";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange=handler;
req.open("GET", serverRelativeUrlOfMyFile, true); // params: (method, url, async)
req.send();
function handler(){
    if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
        // you can now access the file content via the responseText property
        return req.responseText;
    }
}})();
```

But instead of text I get symbols. I need to get only text.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28458091/988264), you can do that with a JavaScript library called [docxtemplater](https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater).

There are also other JS libraries out there to work with `docx` files.

After some quick research, it seems like [docx4js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docx4js) can also read the contents of a file.

I personally use [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/#/) to *generate* documents, but I'm not sure if it can read the contents of an existing doc.

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.